# Switch to another grapic card on my Laptop for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graphics

I use ArcMap on a laptop, a Lenovo Yoga P40. This laptop has two graphic cards: the standard Intel graphic card and a NVidia graphic card designed to be used on graphic softwares (e.g. AutoCAD Inventor). Currently, I think my laptop runs ArcMap with the Intel graphic card, but sometimes I notice it has issues to load and handle ArcMap, therefore I was wondering: is there a way to set my laptop to run ArcMap with the other graphic card?

Answer (score 2):

The graphics card is rarely an issue when experiencing performance problems with ArcGIS (i.e. unless you are doing heavy 3-D visualizations). In fact, I successfully run a version of ArcGIS on a server that does not have a graphics card. Instead, I recommend focusing your attention on increasing 1) the RAM and 2) disk read/write speed by installing a solid state drive.